# Executing dynamic SQL query for filtering data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filter, dynamic-sql

I have to support filtering on a table that has more than 50 columns and all 50 columns can be filtered.

I have filter condition in SQL format like -

```
FirstName = 'Joe' OR SomePolicyId = '9677876' OR Gender = 2 OR IsAlive = 1 OR DOB > '1988/05/16' OR LastName like '%Doe'
```

I am confused which approach should I use.

Approach 1 - 
Create procedure with 50 parameters along with equal/not equal/greater than and other conditions

Approach 2 - 
Executing dynamic sql
Something like

```
set @vquery = 'select [DbId],FirstName,LastName,UserId from [User]  where 1=1 '+@CustomFilter
exec sys.sp_executesql @vsql
```

I know each case has some pros and cons but what can be more benificial ?

Comment: Go for dynamic Query and don't use `where 1=1 '+@CustomFilter` use `from [User]  where '+@CustomFilter`

Comment: Neither option is good and that `1=1` part will return *everything*. Where did this filter clause come from? Why not write [a proper parameterized query](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/) with just the conditions you need each time? Or better yet, why not use an ORM like EF to create the appropriate query? Creating a stored procedure doesn't make a query run faster

Comment: BTW `YYYY/MM/DD` is a localized format which means that filter clause can fail due to parsing/conversion issues. If you use a date-typed parameter you avoid those issues. The server will be able to reuse the execution plan for the parameterized query in the future, improving scalability

Comment: This is a typical "catch all" query. Gail Shaw has a great article about this [here](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and a follow up article [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/revisiting-catch-all-queries)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I can use parameterized query. But I have to pass then 50 parameters. Also I support filters like - equal, not equal, greater than, less than, not in range and other operators depending on property type. It will be very difficult to pass all parameters with operators. Also, field can reoccur in query. Hence I am thinking of dynamic query

Comment: @Vandita parameterized queries are dynamic by **definition**. You have to write that raw string with the parameter definitions after all. When you call [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  you also pass the parameter values *outside* the query string. It's actually easier than creating a string with hard-coded values and remembering to escape everything. In any case, when you create the dynamic query just use the statements and parameters you really need

Comment: @Vandita the *real* problem is trying to use 50 parameters in the first place. Why? Are you trying to create catch-all queries? You *don't* need them if you use EF and constuct the expressions dynamically. A single `.Where()` call creates a `WHERE` statement. *Two* chained calls, eg `.Where(r=>r.DOB.==someDate).Where(r=>r.Gender=GenderEnum.Male)` generate a `WHERE .. AND ..`.